# Assistance building Json data with values as variables

Tags: json, wordpress

Hello I need some help encoding some Json Data when some of the values are "variables".  If I hard code he json data then the API call works.  Here is the hard coded Json data:

```
{
"loanTerm": ["Y30","Y15","Y10","Y7_1"],
"loanType": ["FIXED","ARM"],
"bestExecutionMethod":"BY_POINT_GROUP",
"compensationPayer": "BORROWER",
"lockPeriod": "D30",
 "quoteTypesToReturn": [
 "CLOSEST_TO_ZERO_WITH_FEE","CLOSEST_TO_ZERO_NO_FEE"
],
"propertyZip": 48009,
"fico": 760,
"propertyAppraisedValue": 250000,
"loanAmount": 200000
 }
```

But what i need to do is have code that assembles this Json data using variables in the values.  The call does not work when I do this, here is my code:

```
 $jsonInput = "{
      \"loanTerm\": [" . get_option('loanTerm') . "],
      \"loanType\": [" . get_option('loanType') . "],
          \"bestExecutionMethod\":&nbsp;\"".get_option('best_execution_method')."\",
    \"compensationPayer\":&nbsp;\"".get_option('compensation_payer')."\",
     \"lockPeriod\":&nbsp;\"".get_option('lock_period')."\",
     \"quoteTypesToReturn\": [" . get_option('quote_types_to_return') . "],
     \"dontReturnCachedResults\": " .  get_option('dont_return_cached_results') . ",
      \"propertyZip\": " . get_option('property_zip') . ",
     \"fico\": " . get_option('minFICO') . ",
      \"propertyAppraisedValue\": " . get_option('propertyAppraisedValue') .  ",
      \"loanAmount\": " . get_option('loanAmount') . "
   }";
```

the "get_option()" items are pulling in the variables from the wordpress options table; so those work; so it is something else...

Can anyone see what is wrong with my data?

Thanks so much,  Gerard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inbuilt `json_encode` function to build JSON.

```
 json_encode(array(
'loanTerm' => ((get_option('loanTerm') != false) ? array(get_option('loanTerm')) : 'some_deafault_value'),
'loanType' => ((get_option('loanType') != false) ? array(get_option('loanType')) : 'some_deafault_value'),
'bestExecutionMethod' => ((get_option('best_execution_method') != false) ? get_option('best_execution_method') : 'some_deafault_value'),
'compensationPayer' => ((get_option('compensation_payer') != false) ? get_option('compensation_payer') : 'some_deafault_value'),
'lockPeriod' => ((get_option('lock_period') != false) ? get_option('lock_period') : 'some_deafault_value'),
'quoteTypesToReturn' => ((get_option('quote_types_to_return') != false) ? array(get_option('quote_types_to_return')) : 'some_deafault_value'),
'dontReturnCachedResults' => ((get_option('dont_return_cached_results') != false) ? get_option('dont_return_cached_results') : 'some_deafault_value'),
'propertyZip' => ((get_option('property_zip') != false) ? get_option('property_zip') : 'some_deafault_value'),
'fico' => ((get_option('minFICO') != false) ? get_option('minFICO') : 'some_deafault_value'),
'propertyAppraisedValue' => ((get_option('propertyAppraisedValue') != false) ? get_option('propertyAppraisedValue') : 'some_deafault_value'),
'loanAmount' => ((get_option('loanAmount') != false) ? get_option('loanAmount') : 'some_deafault_value')));
```

Note, this assumes `loanTerm`, `loanType` and `quote_types_to_return` have values like `'a', 'b', 'c'` stored in database

Comment: Hello Igor:  thanks so much for answering this, I had figured out a way to get it to work but it was not optimal.  But your way is much better and I finally had a chance to try it out and it is much better than what I did... Thanks!